# Programatically create order with Authorize.net payment method, already authorized

Tags: orders, payment, payment-methods, authorize.net, programmatically

In short my question is **How can I programatically create an 'Authorize Only' order for Authorize.net for an order that is already authorized?**

I am trying to programatically create orders which have already been authorized on authorize.net.  Order flow is like this:

1. customer places order on 3rd party checkout where card is authorized but not captured
2. customer is redirected back to merchant's website
3. REST API is used to pull over all information related to order
4. Information is used to programatically create order in Magento using custom payment method and automatically invoiced.

Currently this works fine except in cases where the delay for ordering a part is longer than Authorize.net allows for already captured transactions.  Because of this one merchant needs some changes so it behaves the same as when authorize.net is set to "Authorize Only".

what I need to do is create the order using authorize.net payment method, programatically setting the order status, importing the transaction ID,etc

I'm quite stuck.  I've looked through the authroize.net module and spent a lot of time with google.  Any direction, advice, and of course code if available would be appreciated.